# pygame.K_RETURN and pygame.K_BACKSPACE outputting a block

Tags: python, pygame

def Main_Code():

```
user_input = ''
Running= True
while Running:
        FPS.tick(60)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Running = False
                quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_BACKSPACE:
                    user_input = user_input[:-1]
                elif event.type == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    user_input = ''
                else:
                    user_input += event.unicode
                    print (user_input)
        Screen.blit(bg,[0,0])
        text = myfont.render(user_input, True, White)
        Screen.blit(text, (20, 20))
        pygame.display.update()
```

This is not all of my code but I am using pygame to make a falling word game.

The user input is showing on the screen as intended but whenever I press backspace to delete the last character of a word or I press enter to clear the whole user input it returns a box almost like this [].

But from printing the user_input I can see that the user_input is being changed correctly but the screen will still show the user input with the boxes and the text I entered before.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking `event.type == pygame.K_BACKSPACE` when it should be `event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE` instead:

```
...
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_BACKSPACE: # <-- key instead of type
                user_input = user_input[:-1]
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:  # <-- key instead of type
                user_input = ''
            else:
                user_input += event.unicode
                print (user_input)
...
```

You see these strange boxes because the `else` clause is executed in your code and an unprintable character is added to the string.

Comment: Thank you I literally just changed my code to key before this, silly mistake lol. I also added   an if statement to check if the event.codeisalpha()